# How to convert Rasters images (.bmp, .png, .jpg ) into Vectors Images (.svg) in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, image, vector-graphics

I want to convert Raster Images (.bmp, .jpg, .png) into Vector Images (.svg) in iOS SDK.
Is there any API or SDK to convert Raster images into Vector.
How can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API in the standard sdk.  You can try something like svgkit if you can find an algorithm for detecting geometric shapes in a bitmap image... seems like a lot of work.  Do you care that it will be just a big box of pixels?
https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

However remember a vector image is made of geometric objects and a bitmap is just pixels...  So you really want to be going the other direction in terms of scaling.